# ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN

Tags: php, linux, server, rabbitmq, laravel-7

We got an error form laravel 7,  when rabbitMQ Connection in server.
The same server Laravel 5.8  working fine, We use same login details
for both 5.8 and 7. But 7 version only we that issue

ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using the authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.(0, 0) vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:745

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Found the solution, This is an issue from .env file.
Change name of login details from RABBITMQ_LOGIN to RABBITMQ_USER.
it working fine.